# IBM BladeCenter HS12 upgrade?

Tags: ibm, dell-poweredge, bladecenter

I am about to buy a HS12 to replace a PE6950. Is this possible or comparable? It will be used for email service, visio, and MS Project. Currently it uses a lot of bandwidth and it's slow.
Which HS12 do you think is sufficient?

I also wanted to buy another HS12 for Sharepoint and applications for designing IC as well as backups.

Comment: Is it possible? Sure. Can they be compared? Sure. Which bladecenter is sufficient really depends on your load. What is "a lot" of bandwidth, and what is "slow"?

The second sentence isn't actually a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask your IBM VAR - they should be able to assist you choose a suitable server for your specific needs.